# SSN masking numbers to a special character (*) in input on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to mask all the numbers in SSN field to * on keyup. 
I got a solution here [masking numbers to a special character (*) in input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441520/masking-numbers-to-a-special-character-in-input/37441727#37441727) . But how can i get the real values and store it in hidden field. And if the number is changed in-between , it should be updated accordingly. Is there any way to achieve this? example if i type 123 i should change to *** on each number is displayed for few secs. if i remove or delete 2 and place 4, it should give the hidden value 143. type=password not working as number should be visible for few secs before changing to *.

Comment: Create a variable and save it inside. Also make sure this variable has a scope higher that even handler

Comment: its not happening to store in a variable and retrieve. i have tried it

Comment: onkeyup, try something like `variable += this.value.match(/[^*]/g)[0]; this.value = this.value.replace(/[^*]/g, '*')`

Comment: I think you are troubling to retrieve the value of *
Means in textbox you have multiple stars (*)  like 12345 to *****.
you are removing * but realy number should be removed.

Comment: @ Rajesh. i added the above. what is happening is when i type 123 it is showing in alert. but if i remove 3 and add 4, it shows 1234. 3 is not getting removed. And if i add 5 in the start before 1. alert value is 12345. but actually it should return 5124.

Comment: @Ankit. I want to get the orginal value in another hidden field so that i can send to server.

Comment: @Rajesh and Ras If we are thinking deeply then I think we will found this is a nice problem Means Same implementation as input type password but here input type="text"

type="text" not password. Implementation the same thing (means replace number to *) but user can change any * form any position in textbox I want to persist original value to hidden textbox and finally send i.e. 12341 not ***** to server

Comment: @AnkitPandey Please read my second comment, the one with code. I have used a variable to store the value and replacing the value by `*`. So you will have the value. Also notice, the event is **keyup**, so you will have the character and not char code

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for your comment. Actually, we will perform keyup operation on textbox that have * not on hidden textbox. we can do easly just type and convert to *.
Suppose we have ***** and I am just editing using backspace or delete some character by mouse or arrow key selection in the textbox then currently we are editing the * then how we will predict the value.
Please provide any plunker or jsFiddel link if you have.

Answer (score 1):

Ras I have created a code for you.
This is usefull for /[a-zA-Z0-9]/.

Actually, we persist the value in Hidden Element for your server and showing the *** in your UI.

This is a demo and you can customize according to your need.

```js
var arr = [];
function changeValue(event){
  var element = document.getElementById('password');
  var hiddenElement = document.getElementById('hiddenPass');
  var startPos = element.selectionStart;
  var endPos = element.selectionEnd;
  var isTrue = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(element.value);
  // if [0-9] (for number) 
  if((isTrue || event.keyCode == 8)){
    // for deletion
    if(event.keyCode == 8){
      arr.splice(endPos,1);
      setStar(arr);
    }else{
        var val = element.value;
        var obj = {key:val[startPos-1], value:'*'};
        // perticular position insertion
        arr.splice(startPos-1, endPos-startPos, obj);
        setStar(arr);
    }
  }else{
    // for space controlling
    element.value = element.value.trim();
    return;  
  }
}

// star setting
function setStar(arr){
  var element = document.getElementById('password');
  var hiddenElement = document.getElementById('hiddenPass');
  var starText = "";
  var originalText = ""; 
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
     starText += arr[i].value;
     originalText += arr[i].key;
  }
  element.value = starText;
  hiddenElement.value = originalText;
  console.log("HiddenElement", hiddenElement.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="password" type="text" onkeyup="changeValue(event)">
<input id="hiddenPass" type="hidden">
```

Comment: I appreciate your code . but you don't allow to allow to delete the number inbetween nor the cursor to move . and if i copy  3 vlaues say 123 and paste in the box it takes only last in hidden that is 3. instead it should take 123 . and if i keep cursor inbetween two numbers and delete the cursor position comes last. and the added value append to last position in hidden field which does not give the right output. So how can we achieve that scenario..?

Comment: @ ankit - any solution you got ?